# How to use one argument repeatedly in mysql query (NODE.js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to use some argument a few times in same query. How can I do this without duplication of this argument?

This works, but we have to use this argument twice

```
 connection.query('SELECT ? FROM ?', [usr, usr],...)
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work (syntax error):

```
connection.query('SET @param = users; SELECT @param FROM @param',...)
```

Comment: This kind of problem can be indicative of poor design. These are not the parts of the query which would normally be parametricised

Comment: It's just an example. I'll use date as parametr. Eg. `...WHERE date = @param_date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For make it work, you have to do to things:

1. Enable [multiple statement queries](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#multiple-statement-queries)
    `var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});`
2. To keep your variables between queries, many times, you must use MySQL transactions.

`connection.query('start transaction;set @param=?;select @param;commit',[use])`

Read more:

- [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#multiple-statement-queries)
- [Transaction in node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#transactions)
- [Transaction in MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx)